# How to parse and replace incorrect out of century date values in a large csv file

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, vb.net, csv

I'm kind of in an awkward search and replace situation. I'm developing a new database for the my employer and am now at the process of importing old data into the new MySQL database. The issues I'm at crossroads with is that the old database was a LEGACY database by the name of PC-File which used .dbf files, so I found a dbf viewer that would allow me to export the information into a .csv file, but, one file in particular, has over 5000 records of data with incorrect century dates... instead of displaying 12/28/2012 - it will display 12/28/1998. I have searched up and the down the internet trying to find a way to parse the date information between the year ranges of "01/01/1900 - 01/01/1914" and replace the "19" with "20." And to no avail have I been able to find a successful solution.

I hope my question is clear is enough....

I'm open to solutions with excel, C#, vb.net, and MySQL; any input or advice would be GREATLY appreciated.

Here is a sample of my .CSV file:

```
    "CUSTOMER","ORDER_DATE"

    670,"4/18/1913"
    670,"6/25/1913"
    670,"6/25/1913"
    667,"9/18/1912"
    665,"9/14/1912"
    664,"12/8/1920"
    664,"12/8/1920"
    658,"9/23/1911"
    658,"2/6/1912"
    655,"5/11/1911"
    651,"12/10/1910"
    651,"12/10/1910"
    651,"12/14/1910"
    648,"6/2/1910"
    648,"6/2/1910"
    648,"6/2/1910"
    648,"6/2/1910"
```

Thank you guys for any feedback or tips.

Comment: Is it a typo in your question where you say "instead of displaying 12/28/2012 - it will display 12/28/1998"?

Comment: do you just want to `replace the "19" with "20."` if so, you could just walk thru and add 100ys.  But in that case `12/28/1998` becomes `12/28/2098`...the ones in the LIST look like you just need to add 100, but your description is wonky.

Comment: Are you just looking for a one-time solution to do a search and replace on this one CSV file?  Or are you looking for a way to automate some process which will be recurring on a regular basis?

Comment: you are right! that was a typo! I meant that it displays 12/28/1912 instead of 12/28/2012. Thank you for the heads up. And Steven, yes I am looking for a one time solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got it in a database run the following SQL

MySQL Solution:

```
update myTable
set ORDER_DATE = DATE_ADD(ORDER_DATE, INTERVAL 100 YEAR)
where ORDER_DATE between '1900-01-01' and '1914-01-01'; /* Change this cutoff date range as appropriate */
```

Whatever technology you use the logic's the same; select all records for which the date has the wrong year, then correct by adding 100 years.

The Excel solution would be:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=DATE(1900,1,1),A1<=DATE(1914,1,1)),DATE(YEAR(A1)+100,MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),A1)
```

where column A contains your date values.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just parse the dates any way you can, check if they're in the 1900-1914 range you specified, and replace the "19" with "20". Here's one way to handle the parsing and subsequent replacement with Regex:

```
string brokenDate = "648,\"12/10/1912\"";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(brokenDate, @"(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/)19(?=(0[0-9]|1[0-4]))");
string fixedDate = m.Groups[1].Value + "20" + m.Groups[2].Value;
```

You could also alter the Regex to return the whole line if you wanted, instead of just the fixed date as I've done. Or as someone else suggested, it should be possible to modify it a bit to just fix the whole file in one go.